# cascade in mapping by code

Tags: c#, nhibernate

`User` is an entity and `Address` is a component. One `User` can have one `Address`.

`Address` cannot live outside user object. So if user is deleted I want to delete and `Address` object as well.

Is this `Cascade.DeleteOrphan`? and if it is how to set it using `mapping by code` in nhibernate.

Comment: By mapping by code you mean fluent-nhibernate?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/q/9573326/1236044

Comment: @agustingMeriles no, not fluent. I mean mapping by code approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use cascading. Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) for more details.